# Some questions about meta keyword and search engine

Tags: magento2, search, seo

I've got some questions about **keyword** and **search engine** as below.

**1. does meta keyword support international language?**

- When I type English meta keywords it searched on our website but when
  I type Korean meta keywords It doesn't work. Does meta keyword
  support international language in different language store?

  ***(Ex: English store-Korean meta keywords, Korean store-Chinese meta
  keywords)***

  **2. International Language product name isn't searched properly.**
- When I search English name product ***(Ex:"Beaumont Summit Kit")*** most
  letter of product name can be searched on search engine ***(Ex: "bea"
  "sum" "kit" "beaumont" "summit", ...)***.

  But when I search Korean name
  product ***(Ex:"톰포드 블랙 수트")*** It only can search by keyword "톰포드". Search
  engine can't find product by keyword "블랙" and "수트" even in Korean
  store view, it weird. Is there another way to search more
  specifically in Korean language?

  I wish I could find answer.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem with Chinese. Did you find a way to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize different languages then you will have to create different pages with the languages you want, and use this tag with language, then crawler will understand about your website languages.

rel="alternate" hreflang="x"